# How to set and get value from the composite key

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, drools

I am trying to set the value `cid` in student class using `SubjectMark->private String cid;`
How to set and get value in my controller.
Entity's and controller method below:

```
@Entity
public class Student implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @EmbeddedId
    private SubjectMark id;
    private String fullName;
    private Integer totalMarks;
    private Double percentage;
    private String grade;
    //Setters and getters
}


//Composit class
@Embeddable
public class SubjectMark implements Serializable {
//Composit key
private String cid;
//Setters and getters

}
```

In my controller I try to set value like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="getstdata",method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String getstdata(@RequestParam(value="cid")String cid){  
//Some code
try{

Student st=new Student();
st.getId().setCid(cid);//Set value like this but it is getting null pointer exception
//some code

//retuen some value
}
```

Please help me!

Comment: Hello veer! There is no need to change the title to add "Solved" on Stack Overflow. That information is signalled clearly by simply accepting an answer, like you've already done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st part of question:

> I am trying to set the value cid in student class using SubjectMark->private String cid; How to set and get value in my controller.

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Student implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@EmbeddedId
private SubjectMark subjectMarkId;
private String otherField;
// setters, getters
}

//Composite class
@Embeddable
public class SubjectMark implements Serializable {
private String cId;
// setter, getter
}


//Controller
@GetMapping(value = "getstdata")
public String getStData(@RequestParam(value="cid") String cid) {
Student student = new Student();

student.setSubjectMark(new SubjectMark());
student.getSubjectMark().setCId(cid);//cid value dynamic
// some other code
return "";
}
```

2nd part of question:

Now, one of the reason null exception happens when you try to call a method(either setter or getter) from a null object.

Comment: ho thanks.its working . I tried this on Student st=new Student();
  SubjectMark stid=new SubjectMark();
  stid.setCid(cid);
  st.setId(stid); this one also working.

Answer (score 0):

you need to write a get set method in your class I guess...
try writing something like

private String cid;

public String Cid { get => cid; set => cid = value; }

Comment: thanks for quick response-@MiracleGirl-. My problem is not in entity . how i am set and get value cid (cid value comes from front-end) in controller class.